# Do airliners have an "anti-pilot" warning system?

Tags: safety, air-traffic-control, radar, aircraft-systems

In February 2014 a co-pilot hijacked [Ethopian Airlines flight 702](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethiopian_Airlines_Flight_702_hijacking) and took it to Switzerland.

Now in March there is some speculation that [Malaysia Airlines flight 370](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_370) may have been hijacked and destroyed by the pilots - maybe they took a nose dive into the Andaman Sea?

So my question is this: is there an automatic or say **anti-pilot warning system** on commercial airliners?

In other words, a system that is non-maskable (can't be disabled by the pilot) and which will automatically warn ATC about unexpected conditions (like a sudden decrease in altitude)?

Comment: I'm not sure 'anti-pilot' is the phrase you're looking for here, but I don't know what else to suggest.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The system you're asking about is called radar: ATC should monitor it to see what the plane is doing and ask what is going on when something unexpected happens.

It's hard to "automate" these kinds of alerts. For example, a sudden dive can also be cause by an uncontrolled control-surface hard-over (like the [boeing 737 rudder problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_rudder_issues) that brought down 2 planes), or a loss of cabin pressurization (which requires a rapid descent to an altitude where your passengers can breathe).

The other option is having a second person in the cockpit who can wrest control away from the disobedient pilot (or let people in the cockpit to help).

Comment: Does a radar show altitude?

Comment: @AdityaPatil Yes, secondary radar shows altitude. But the radar transponder can be switched of by the pilot and then there is no altitude visible. Also, over sea / ocean there is often no radar coverage.

Comment: A dive can also be because of a depressurization.

Comment: some primary radars can provide altitude (by looking at the angle and range) but that is inaccurate

Comment: @lnafziger yes, but in tht case, pilot would give a distress signal.In case of MH370, there was no such signal.

Comment: Anything other than radar that pilot can't disable?

Comment: @AdityaPatil; there's not such thing as "can't be disabled" as soon as it's aboard the aircraft.

Comment: @AdityaPatil if it is electronic then the pilot can simply pull the fuse

Comment: @AdityaPatil and what would it do anyway? Utterly useless, unless you're hoping for some system where you can remotely take control over the aircraft at any time. And a hacker/terrorist would just love that capability.

Comment: @AdityaPatil - I think you're missing a more major point.  We don't want to put a pilot in a situation where a computer forces control away from them.  Computers can't be programmed for every contingency and they can't think creatively, so it could be dangerous.  Rather, airlines do their best to screen pilots.  A pilot of a 777 has to have several thousand hours of flight time before they are allowed to fly that plane, they are screened throughout the process of gaining hours.  That's how this issue is dealt with, not by letting the computer steal control.

Comment: @DeltaLima Secondary radar only tells ATC the reading of the plane's altimeter: it doesn't independently measure the plane's altitude. There was a crash (sorry, can't remember which but there was a *Mayday* episode about it) in which the flight crew were convinced that their faulty altimeters were correct because they agreed with the figures that ATC was giving them over the radio: neither side realised that the ATC display was just a parroting the incorrect altimeter reading.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think it was [Aeroperu 603](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroper%C3%BA_Flight_603).

Comment: @reirab I think you're right, yes.